# Your theme has 8 widget areas, but this particular page doesn’t display them

Tags: widgets

CUrrently I downloaded one wordpress theme. In few pages i have widget area . But i want to display in one more page. On that page i am getting message inside customize->widget as "**Your theme has 8 widget areas, but this particular page doesn’t display them.
You can navigate to other pages on your site while using the Customizer to view and edit the widgets displayed on those pages.**"

Can i show it one more page. anyone have idea then let me know. please see attachment for more clarity/
Thank in advance

[image]

Comment: You can see all available widget areas in _Appearance > Widgets_. Please note that this isn't really a development question, which is what this site is for, and would be better suited to the WordPress support forums.

Comment: Actually i m new in wordpess. So exactly dont have idea, But in few pages widget display properly.